# SQLite insert or replace into

Tags: sqlite

Assuming I have the Database structure with 2 colums + rowid column. Whenever i do this sql statement:

```
REPLACE INTO player (id,credits)  VALUES ('123123',10);
```

However i seen for values that already exist,the data gets updated but the ROW ID gets incremented. Why is this so? Is it possible to keep the ROW ID consistent?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

with replace, the row gets deleted then reinserted, you'll more than likely have to do update

Answer (score 0):

`REPLACE` stands for `INSERT OR REPLACE`, and practically, is an `INSERT` statement. You need to use `UPDATE`.